# Firewall rule enable with cloudflare API

Tags: api, curl, firewall, cloudflare

We need to change status for cloudflare firewall rule with API.
In [Docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/api/cf-firewall-rules/json-object) I see that `'paused' Returns true when the rule is not active. Use 'ref' to enable/disable the rule.` and `'ref' A short string for tagging rules.`
But we don’t understand what is the ref and how we can use ref for enable/disable firewall rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation was misleading, you just need to override the "Paused".